Issue with building a React Native app in Xcode caused by a module not found
The React Native app already works on an Android emulator using Android Studio. But it doesn't work on an iOS simulator using Xcode. After attempting to build the project on Xcode, I got this error: A0Auth0/A0Auth0.modulemap' not found.
I tried uninstalling the pod folder and the Podfile.lock file, then I did cd ios and pod install. After that, on Xcode, I went to Product>Clean Build Folder + Clear All Issues. But I still get the same error.
Update 1: I tried running the iOS app on an iPhone that has wifi turned on and it worked. So I tried turning on the wifi on the simulator before running the app but the app still didn't work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have experienced this, I accidentally opened the .xcproject file instead of .xcworkspace in my Xcode. Opening the correct file fixed the issue.

I opened the .xcworkspace file in Xcode but I still get the same error
